# User-Defined Aggregate in SQL Server 2008 - How to deploy with MaxByteSize = -1?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clr, user-defined-aggregate

I read [here](http://www.halhayes.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,127faa81-511d-462f-9b48-3272142837f9.aspx) (and elsewhere) that it's possible, in SQL Server 2008, to build a user-defined aggregate which can return a string longer than 8000 characters.  This is exactly what I need.

Supposedly, the method is to set maxByteSize to -1 instead of a number btw 1 and 8000; this should allow any size up to 2GB.

For some reason, apparently, you can't deploy straight from Visual Studio 2008 if you use this setting; so you need to manually deploy.

So: I build my project - GroupConcat (which is supposed to simulate MySQL's group_concat aggregator) - which gives me, in the project's bin folder, a file "SqlClassLibrary.dll".  Per the instructions on the above-linked page, I build the assembly in SQL Server.  The command executes successfully.  However, when I try to actually *use* the groupconcat aggregator:

**`select department, dbo.groupconcat(projectNumber) from projectleads group by department`**

...it says it can't be found.  This all works fine if I set maxByteSize to 8000 and deploy directly from within VS2008, but I need >8000.  Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
-dan

**NOTE:**  I do specifically need to have a groupconcat aggregator function rather than using some of the SQL Server tricks I've often seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...  After building the solution in Vis Studio, assuming I've dropped the .dll it creates into c:\temp and called it GroupConcat.dll:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY GroupConcat from 'C:\temp\GroupConcat.dll' with permission_set = safe
GO

CREATE AGGREGATE groupconcat(@input nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
EXTERNAL NAME GroupConcat
GO
```

That does it.

Answer (score 3):

Alternately, you can use `MaxSize` property of `SqlFacetAttribute` to to indicate the varchar size. Note that in the example below I applied this attribute to the `SqlString` parameters in the `Accumulate` method and to the return value of the `Terminate` method. This results in the following SQL signature:

`AGGREGATE [dbo].[Concatenate] (@value nvarchar(max), @order int, @seperator nvarchar(max)) RETURNS nvarchar(max)`

```
[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
    Format.UserDefined,
    IsInvariantToOrder      = true,
    IsInvariantToNulls      = true,
    IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,
    IsNullIfEmpty           = false,
    MaxByteSize             = -1)]
public struct Concatenate : IBinarySerialize
{
    public void Init();

    public void Accumulate([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] SqlString value,
                                                    SqlInt32  order,
                           [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] SqlString seperator);

    public void Merge(Concatenate group);

    [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
    public SqlString Terminate();

    public void Read(BinaryReader r);

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w);
}
```

I don't know if this is any more "correct" than what you ended up doing, but it seems more natural.